# COUNT with IF Statement in MS-ACCESS and GROUPING

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, count

I am a newbie and Looking forward for you guys to help me out in this problem. I am creating an attendance database. I have three tables Attendance, student and Grades but i need only Attendance table to calculate attendance. i want to write a query which should return me Names of Students from Attendance table in DISTINCT, number of Presents of Student and Number of Absents of Student. I am stuck with COUNT Statement with IF, couldn't figure them out. I hope you guys can help

My Tables
Attendance : ID, Student, Attendance [Present/Absent],Att_date, Remarks
Student: Stud_ID,Stud_Name, Class
Grades: Stud_ID,Grades

I want the query to return like

---

### Student                   Presents               Absents

Stud1                       10                   5
Stud2                       9                    6

Comment: Sorry I should have used some HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
TRANSFORM COUNT(Attendance)
SELECT Student, Attendance, 
FROM TableAttendance
GROUP BY Student
PIVOT Attendance
```